# Using rsync but cannot get copy to be mirror

Tags: cron, rsync

I've set up a cron job to try and periodically clone/mirror some data from one hard drive to another for emergency restoration purposes. I'm using rsync and finding that the sync is not happening the way I had hoped. The files in the drive2 location contain files that have been deleted on drive1 since time has elapsed between cron jobs.

Can someone look over what I'm using and tell me what switches I should be using instead?  To be clear, I am trying to get an exact duplicate of the data from source to destination.

```
rsync -av --progress -L /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1/sharedfolders/downloads/ /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-2/cloned/downloads/ --delete
```

*EDIT*  For whatever reason the above works fine for some of my dirs but not all of them.  I switched to this:

rsync  --recursive --delete /source/ /destination/

and it is working fine.  I used this site to build the working command:

https://www.rsyncinator.app/web

Comment: Could you also share your crontab entry?

Comment: @joeljpa  It's from a script and that's copy paste from the script

Comment: *"I've set up a cron job to try and periodically clone/mirror some data"* - it could be that your cron job is not calling your rsync script when you think it does. That's why joeljpa asked to see your crontab entry.

Comment: Apologies. It is part of a script that does other rsync copies and those appear to be working. Will run it by hand and see what results I get